# What widget should i use in Python Tkinter to write multiple values of a variable after the press of a button?

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, textarea, calculus

I am doing a school project in which i need to recreate this  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeJOB.png).

I am using Python Tkinter and in the red highlighted are i have to output the values of the x variable which are calcualted by some methods.

My problem is that i don't know what kind of Tkinter widget i have to use.(i was thinking of Text Are but i m not sure how i should write on different lines)
Also i have to rewrite the whole window if i press "Calculate" again.

PS. I m a noob

Comment: Also, if you know a Widget for the Graph i would really Appreciate. Thank you!

Comment: Look at [`tk.Listbox`](http://web.archive.org/web/20201111194626/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm). For a graph look at the `matplotlib` library.